# Memory leak on vector._Reallocate() in Visual C++ Memory Debugger

Tags: c++, visual-studio, memory-leaks, stdvector

I have two vectors of pointers:

1. A vector containing pointers to all objects
2. A temporary vector containing pointers to some of the objects in the above vector. Each frame, this vector is cleared and pointers are then added again.

No objects are created or deleted during these frames.

According to Visual Studio's memory profiler I get a memory leak, in vector._Reallocate() every time I add a pointer to this vector.

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4Ky3.png

My question is:
Does vector.push_back() allocate something that is not deallocated later, or is Visual Studio's memory profiler just confused because I'm clearing a vector without destroying the elements? This only happens in Debug mode - not in Release.

I understand that the _Reallocate(..)-method allocates space on the heap, but since I clear the vector this should not cause a leak, I suppose?

*Update:  using std::list instead of std:.vector solves the "problem" - though I don't know if it really is a problem or not*

**Update2: It DOES happen in Release mode as well. I was a little bit confused by the output, but I get the same problem there**

**Update3: I have attached some code that can reproduce the problem. I could only reproduce the problem if I store the vectors in a multidimensional array, like in the original problem.

```
class MyClassContainer
{
public:
    std::vector<MyClass*> vec;
};

int main(int args, char **argv)
{
    std::vector<MyClass*> orig;
    MyClassContainer copy[101][101];
    for(int i = 0; i < 101; i++)
        orig.push_back(new MyClass());
    while (true)
    {
        int rnd = std::rand() * 100 / RAND_MAX; int rnd2 = std::rand() * 100 / RAND_MAX;
        for (int i = 0; i < 101; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 101; j++)
                copy[i][j].vec.clear(); // this should clear all??
        copy[rnd2][rnd].vec.push_back(orig[rnd]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Update 4:** *The memory debugger shows an increasing number of heap allocations as time goes. However, I noticed now that if I wait for a long time the number of new heap allocations per second decreases towards 0. So apparently it's not really a memory leak.
It seems that when each vector in the array has been pushed to at least once nothing more gets allocated on the heap. I don't understand why though.*

Comment: *"This only happens in Debug mode - not in Release."* - Debug mode might check for memory leaks, Release mode does not.

Comment: But why would vector.push_back(pointer to object) cause a memory leak? Of course vector.push_back(new object(...)) would, but I'm not allocating anything on the heap.

Comment: Can you produce a [mcve]?

Comment: Are these raw pointers or smart pointers? sounds like a reference count problem

Comment: @NathanOliver: Sorry, I should have done that before. Thank you for reminding me! See updated post above.

Comment: @ofek-shilon: Raw pointers, as used in the updated version of my post

Answer (score 0):

Not to point out the obvious... but you are not freeing the MyClass objects created here.  Since you have a vector of raw pointers, they must be freed (and freed only once).

```
orig.push_back(new MyClass());
```

Put this at the end of main and your leaks should go away.  Perhaps you were misled by the location of the leak report?  vector::push_back() should not leak.

```
// Free the objects
for (int i = 0; i < orig.size(); i++) {
    delete orig[i];
    orig[i] = 0;    // not necessary, but good defensive practice
}
```

I also recommend using smart-pointers, for exactly these cases.

PS: Not really my business, but what is this algorithm doing?  That sure is a lot of vectors...

Comment: Thank you. You are right, I should definitely free the objects before exiting.
However, that is not the "leak" I am refering to.
The memory debugger shows an increasing number of heap allocations as time goes. However, I noticed now that if I wait for a long time the number of new heap allocations per second decreases towards 0. So apparently it's not really a memory leak.
It seems that when each vector in the array has been pushed to at least once nothing more gets allocated on the heap. I don't understand why though.

Comment: And to answer your question: In the original code I divide a huge collection of objects into a structure similar to an octree (but without recursive resolution). Each grid cell contains a vector of elements.